# Boolean columns in Hive are loaded as NULL

Tags: hive

I have the following input csv file

```
10418872, fever, FALSE
10418872, shortness of breath, FALSE
10418872, shortness of breath, FALSE
10418872, shortness of breath, FALSE
```

I created a hive table using these commands and loaded data in it

```
create database bpo;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE bpo.adverse(patientId INT, symptom STRING, severe BOOLEAN) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/landingzone/hive/adverse';
LOAD DATA INPATH '/landingzone/adverse-effects.csv' INTO TABLE bpo.adverse;
```

However now when I query the data in hive

```
10418872         fever  NULL
10418872         shortness of breath    NULL
10418872         shortness of breath    NULL
10418872         shortness of breath    NULL
```

why did the boolean columns become null? I tried changing case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please trim the leading space before FALSE and try.

I tested with the above input as follows, you can see the difference in the output:

```
10418872, fever,FALSE
10418872, shortness of breath,FALSE
10418872, shortness of breath, FALSE
10418872, shortness of breath, FALSE
```

I got the result in hive as :

```
adverse.patientid  adverse.symptom  adverse.severe
10418872         fever  false
10418872         shortness of breath    false
10418872         shortness of breath    NULL
10418872         shortness of breath    NULL
```